# How to make linux have fixed IP address

Tags: ubuntu, router, ip

I have window server 2008 installed.

Inside that ihave installed ubuntu  using VMware

Now i want that ubuntu should always have local ip of 10.0.11.5.

How can i configue that.

I am using Netgear router and i have not found any option in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Edit /etc/network/interfaces.
2. Add lines similar to these:

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.100
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   ```
3. Save file.
4. /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Sheesh, that formatting got messed up and for some reason, I'm unable to re-format correctly. Anyway, details on how it's supposed to look are here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/change-ubuntu-system-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address.html

Comment: add more spaces to the front of the lines ... i think you need to indent each line with 8 spaces (instead of 4) for it to show up right.  essentially, markdown's reading it as a continuation of the "2." block.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the rc.networking or change the permissions to make it non-executable or rename it so that the boot process cannot find the rc.network. You can put this into rc.local which is the script that loads when the boot up has finished.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

This will force your `eth0` adapter to be set. No need to issue `auto eth0` as the kernel should have detected your `eth0` adapter anyway. Then to confirm it issue `ifconfig eth0` to check your ip address which should match what is in the example above. See below for an example

```
# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap 100Mbps Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:C0:90:B3:42
          inet addr 192.168.0.100 Bcast 192.168.0.255 Mask 255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU 1500  Metric 0
          RX packets 3136 errors 217 dropped 7 overrun 26
          TX packets 1752 errors 25 dropped 0 overrun 0
```

Look at the `UP` indicator, that tells you the nic's ip address is active and running.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.